# Using for loop to convert colnames in R

Tags: r, for-loop, paste

I am trying to use for loop c("2000", "2001",..., "2011") to rewrite the following code. Each data frame include variables "emp_01", "emp_02" and so on. To distinguish these variables, I would like to use suffixes "emp_01.2000", "emp_02.2000" and convert "fips" for merge. Could you tell me how to write for loop in this case?

```
colnames(df_2000) <- paste(colnames(df_2000), "2000", sep = ".")
df_2000  <-  df_2000 %>%
   rename(fips = fips.2000)
colnames(df_2001) <- paste(colnames(df_2001), "2001", sep = ".")
df_2001  <-  df_2001 %>%
   rename(fips = fips.2001)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `mget` to get the objects in a `list` and then  change the values

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^df_\\d{4}$')) %>%
       map(~ .x %>%
          rename_at(vars(starts_with('fips')), ~ str_remove(., '\\.\\d{4}$')))
```

It is better to keep the objects in the list instead of updating the original objects.  But, if we need

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

If we need to join all the `list` elements

```
reduce(lst1, full_join, by = 'fips')
```

Or if we consider to join all the `data.frame` within the `list` with another dataset 'pop'

```
map(lst1, ~ full_join(.x, pop, by = 'fips'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I got ```lst1$df_2000$emp_1.2000``` and so on. How do I get ``` lst1$emp_1.2000``` etc? I have other data frames and merge these data frames by fips like merge(lst1, pop, all=T, by='fips')

Comment: @hrkshr do you have a nested `list`.  Based on the code showed, the 'df_2000' is a data.frame

Comment: @hrkshr i updated the post.  Do you want to merge each data.frame in the `lst1` with a new data.frame 'pop'?